# Replacing column value with another

Tags: r

I'm trying to clean a data set that looks like this.

```
Name  Mon    Tue
abc   44970  44971
def   NA     1
gh    1      NA
```

I would like to change every '1' into the date of that column. (I will format later)
Desired output:

```
Name  Mon    Tue
abc   44970  44971
def   NA     44971
gh    44970  NA
```

I tried using.

```
test$Mon[test$Mon == '1'] <- '44970'
```

This works, but does not solve the issue. I would have to do it for Mon - Fri. as well as for 200 sheets that get read in - all with different dates. How would I include something that just references the date in that column without hardcoding the date?

edit for example date:

```
> dput(head(test))
structure(list(delete = c("...1", "#", "1", "1", "4", "1"), Employee = c("CBRE Downtown Corporate Office Weekly Check-In", 
"Employee Name", "Ad, Ant", "Ak, Ki", "Al, An", 
"Am, Ni"), Manager = c("...3", "Manager Name", "Ha, Er", 
"Dahlin, Alexandra", "Kruger, Katie", "Da, Al"), Dept. = c("...4", 
"Department", "Tram", "A", "T", 
"Shared Office Services"), Mon = c("44970", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA
), Tue = c("44971", NA, NA, "1", "1", "1"), Wed = c("44972", 
NA, "1", NA, "1", NA), Thur = c("44973", NA, NA, NA, "1", NA), 
    Fri = c("44974", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Comment: What should we assume about what date to use: Is the date always in the 2nd row? Always in the first row after headers? Always in the row with Name abc? Always the first value that looks like an excel date in the range you're expecting, e.g. between 44000 and 48000?

Comment: Can you share a data example as code we can run and load? for instance you could run `dput(head(test))` and paste the output into your question.

Comment: @JonSpring just added dput edit, let me know if that helps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll assume that the data is numeric and that we want to replicate the first value for each column when the value is 1.

```
library(dplyr)
test %>% 
  mutate(across(Mon:Fri, ~ifelse(. == 1, first(.), .)))
  # mutate(across(Mon:Fri, ~ifelse(. == 1, max(., na.rm = TRUE), .))) # alternate
  #  suggested by @M and @TarJae in case it's more reliable for this data
```

Result

```
# A tibble: 6 × 9
  delete Employee                                       Manager           Dept.             Mon   Tue   Wed   Thur  Fri  
  <chr>  <chr>                                          <chr>             <chr>             <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>
1 ...1   CBRE Downtown Corporate Office Weekly Check-In ...3              ...4              44970 44971 44972 44973 44974
2 #      Employee Name                                  Manager Name      Department        NA    NA    NA    NA    NA   
3 1      Ad, Ant                                        Ha, Er            Tram              NA    NA    44972 NA    NA   
4 1      Ak, Ki                                         Dahlin, Alexandra A                 NA    44971 NA    NA    NA   
5 4      Al, An                                         Kruger, Katie     T                 NA    44971 44972 44973 NA   
6 1      Am, Ni                                         Da, Al            Shared Office Se… NA    44971 NA    NA    NA
```

Comment: ```max(.x, na.rm = T)``` instead of `first`? That'd be less error prone.

Comment: It might be. Unclear if there ever might be multiple "dates" in the column, or larger values than those dates. Are you expecting that sometimes the first row might be NA and we'd want to pull from another row? It's unclear from the description what sort of edge cases are worth solving around.

Comment: @M-- max might do the trick, the first value isn't always the date. this works for my needs thanks!

Comment: @JonSpring yeah, it is unclear, but `max` would handle a lot of the edge cases that I can think of. I just wanted to offer an alternative.

Answer (score 1):

One solution with `sum()` :-)

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  mutate(across(-Name, ~ifelse(.==1, sum(., na.rm = TRUE), .)))

 Name   Mon   Tue
1  abc 44970 44971
2  def    NA 44971
3   gh 44970    NA
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use dplyr mutate with a case_when statement. For example:

```
library(dplyr)

test %>%
  mutate(
    Mon = case_when(
      Mon == '1' ~ 44970,
      TRUE ~ Mon
    )
  )
```

This will ensure that only the values == '1' are affected.
Repeat for Tue, Wed etc

Comment: The OP is looking for a solution that will reference the date in the column without hardcoding the date.

Answer (score 0):

If we use a data frame like this:

```
> dput(val)
structure(list(V1 = c(44970, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), V2 = c(44971, 
NA, NA, 1, 1, 1), V3 = c(44972, NA, 1, NA, 1, NA), V4 = c(44973, 
NA, NA, NA, 1, NA), V5 = c(44974, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

which is format like this without tibble badness,

```
     V1    V2    V3    V4    V5
1 44970 44971 44972 44973 44974
2    NA    NA    NA    NA    NA
3    NA    NA     1    NA    NA
4    NA     1    NA    NA    NA
5    NA     1     1     1    NA
6    NA     1    NA    NA    NA
```

A solution in base is:

```
mapply(`[`, val[1, ], val[-1, ])
```

which gives:

```
> mapply(`[`, val[1, ], val[-1, ])
     V1    V2    V3    V4 V5
[1,] NA    NA    NA    NA NA
[2,] NA    NA 44972    NA NA
[3,] NA 44971    NA    NA NA
[4,] NA 44971 44972 44973 NA
[5,] NA 44971    NA    NA NA
```

as desired.